# How to restrict overlapping of element with relative-absolute styles

Tags: css

I am trying to develop multiselect from scratch. Of course I have to use relative-absolute for drop-down menu (I need to render it over other elements).

Because I also have mobile "sliding" menu I faced with problem: my multiselect render above my menu

[image]

Below you can see other conditions:

[image]

Menu:

```
.button-panel {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100vh - 75px);
    position: absolute;
    top: 75px;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    background-color: transparent;
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(15px);
    backdrop-filter: blur(15px);
    padding-right: 0;
```

Input:

```
.input-area  {
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: var(--grey-light);
    display: flex;
}
```

Drop-down:

```
.select-content {
    height: 120px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: var(--grey-light);
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background-color: var(--pink-super-light);
}
```

How can I solve this? I have to use relative-absolute because I need render drop-down above other elements, but under side-menu. I tryed to use z-index inside menu and drop-down but didn't get any usful result. Probably I missed something.. Are there workarounds mb?

Objective: develop multiselect with drop-down which render above other elements but works correctly with side-menu.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code and names are not clear ever for sorry, but I will try to help.

---

Let's clarify somethings in the positioning in css.

First, you need to know what exactly is the difference between the most used 3 types of positions in the market.

**• Position `Relative`:**
To move the element from its own place from its own sides.

**• Position `Absolute`:**
To move the element from the sides of his first positioned parent.

**• Position `Fixed`:**
To fix the element place from  the window sides.

---

And now, let's analyze your code...

First, the menu needs to take the `fixed` position not the absolute, because it needs to has a specific place of the entire screen.

Second, the drop-down menu activation button needs the position `relative` so you can position the options `absolute` to it.

So what you must do is to have a parent for the whole drop-down menu input and content that has a `relative` position, and the children will be absolute.

---

These are some notes about positions..

But what about overlapping elements over each others?!

This is handled by the `z-index` property, and this property just takes numbers, so the higher the number value of the `z-index` the higher ordered the element on the screen.

But note that, the `z-index` property will not work on any element ever until the element takes a value for the `position` which can be absolute or others but not static, or the element takes any `transform` value which can be `scale(1)` for example.

Now I think your problem is very easy to solve yourself.

Answer (score 1):

For z-index to work, your dropdown class will have to have a position element, so before adding z-index to select-content class add position absolute to it.